# android httpGet issue

Tags: android, http

I am trying to execute the following link using following code:

```
class httpget{
HttpGet httpGet=null;

public void linkexecute(){
String url="http://<server>/<path>/action=send&msg=new message";
httpGet= new HttpGet(url); // line 1
....
}

at line 1 it is giving error "Illegal arguement exception"    
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 77: http://<server>/<path>/sms.json?action=send&msg=new message    
at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:970)    
at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:75)    
at com.sms.login.LoginService.sendSms(LoginService.java:143)
```

Whereas there's no error for given below URL which has no gaps in words of "msg="

```
String url="http://<server>/<path>/action=send&msg=newmessage";
```

How can I resolve the issue of gap in words in URL?

Answer (score 15):

Here, i give you one function that will remove all invalid characters from the url . Please pass your url in this function and you will get a new url with encoded strings.

```
public static String convertURL(String str) {

    String url = null;
    try{
    url = new String(str.trim().replace(" ", "%20").replace("&", "%26")
            .replace(",", "%2c").replace("(", "%28").replace(")", "%29")
            .replace("!", "%21").replace("=", "%3D").replace("<", "%3C")
            .replace(">", "%3E").replace("#", "%23").replace("$", "%24")
            .replace("'", "%27").replace("*", "%2A").replace("-", "%2D")
            .replace(".", "%2E").replace("/", "%2F").replace(":", "%3A")
            .replace(";", "%3B").replace("?", "%3F").replace("@", "%40")
            .replace("[", "%5B").replace("\\", "%5C").replace("]", "%5D")
            .replace("_", "%5F").replace("`", "%60").replace("{", "%7B")
            .replace("|", "%7C").replace("}", "%7D"));
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return url;
}
```

Comment: By my count this creates about 30 String objects...gross.

Answer (score 12):

You should definitely use `URLEncoder.encode(String, String)`

Answer (score 5):

I think the issue is with parametrs of URL. Instead of Encoding or replacing whole URL, just encode the parametres like this:

```
Url: http://myHost.com/mail.do?address=New York city@&time=12$3;
right url:http://myHost.com/mail.do? + UrlEncode(address) + "&" + UrlEncode(time);
```

Another example is:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("email", URLEncoder.encode(loginStr));
params.put("pass", URLEncoder.encode(passwStr));
Model.doAuthUser(params, userCallback);
```

Model.doAuthUser loks like following:

```
 String url = "http://myHost.com/mail.do";
 if (params != null) {
 url += "?";
 Boolean beginAddParams = true;
 for (Entry<String, String> entryParams : params.entrySet()) {
 if (!beginAddParams) {
   url +="&";
  } else {
   beginAddParams = false;
  }
  url += entryParams.getKey() + "=" + entryParams.getValue();
 }
```

And use the `url` wherever you want.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should use %20 instead of the space

Comment: Yep, do a String replace for " " to %20.

Comment: Its good when you just have space in you url, but there are many other characters,that then give IllegalCharacterException.

Answer (score 1):

The URLEncoder did not work out for me when I was posting variables to my webservice, because it was replacing all the parameters. I ended up using

```
URI uri = new URI("http", "server", "/path", "action=send&msg=newmessage", null);
String url = uri.toASCIIString();
```

and later on parsing my downloaded data using httpPost with the httpClient ...

```
String xml = null;
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

I assume that httpGet method will work the same way.