# Undefined variable error in php while updating value from android

Tags: php, android, http-get

I am trying to update a field in database but getting undefined variable error from my php page...

My code is:

```
Intent myintent = getIntent();
    //mdate = intent.getStringExtra("mdate");
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mdate.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    title=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null){ 
      mtitle = extras.getString("title");
      stime = extras.getString("mtime");
      sdate = extras.getString("mdate");
      cvenue = extras.getString("venue");
    }

    title.setText(mtitle);
    title.setFocusable(false);
    cdate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    cdate.setText(sdate);
    cdate.setFocusable(false);
    venue=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    venue.setText(cvenue);
    venue.setFocusable(false);
    ctime=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    ctime.setText(stime);
    ctime.setFocusable(false);
    fdate=cdate.getText().toString();
    ftime=ctime.getText().toString();
    ftitle=title.getText().toString();
    fvenue=venue.getText().toString();
    fattend=uid.toString();

    cnfrm=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);       
    cnfrm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try
            {
                String str_params=URLEncoder.encode("res="+resy.toString()+
                        "&title="+ftitle+
                        "&venue="+fvenue+
                        "&cdate="+fdate+
                        "&ctime="+ftime+
                        "&attend="+fattend,"UTF-8");                    
                get= new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2/meetingschedular/confirmmeet.php?"+str_params);                           
                client= new DefaultHttpClient();
                res=client.execute(get);
                in=res.getEntity().getContent();
                StringBuffer str= new StringBuffer();                       
                int ch;
                while((ch=in.read())!=-1)
                    {
                        str.append((char)ch);   
                    }
            String tmp=str.toString();
            tmp=tmp.trim();
            //txt.setText(tmp);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tmp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(flag.equals(tmp))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tmp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }   
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry cannot confirm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
                {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
        }
    });
```

And my php code is :

```
 <?php 
// Connects to your Database 
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('meetingschedulardata',$con);
if(!$con)
{
die("can not connect".mysql_error());
}
if (isset($_GET['title']))
{
    $title=$_GET['title'];
}
if(isset($_GET['cdate']))
{
    $cdate=$_GET['cdate'];
}
if(isset($_GET['ctime']))
{
    $ctime=$_GET['ctime'];
}
if(isset($_GET['attend']))
{
    $attend=$_GET['attend'];
}
if(isset($_GET['venue']))
{
    $venue=$_GET['venue'];
}
if(isset($_GET['res']))
{
    $res=$_GET['res'];
}
$sdate = strtotime($cdate);
$new_date = date('Y-m-d', $sdate);
$stime = strtotime($ctime);
$new_time = date('h:i:s', $stime);
//echo "till now it works..";
$order="Update meetingdetails SET status='$res' WHERE status IS NULL AND title='$title' AND mdate='$new_date' AND mtime='$new_time' AND attendees='$attend' AND venue='$venue'";
$result=mysql_query($order,$con);
//echo "It still works";
if($result==1)
{
echo "true";
}
else{
echo "false".mysql_error();
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I want to update my status field in my db but unable to do that..
The error its showing is like this

[image]

Pls suggest me some thing so that I can run my application correctly... Thnx in advance

Comment: What is the value of str_params in your Java before you send the request?

Comment: define your all var to blank value first or initialize them  or turn off php warnings from via php.ini

Comment: nothing i have encoded all the values and put it into str_params.... @karmafunk

Comment: I dnt get what ur telling.. can u tell me in details pls.. @RakeshSharma

Comment: I know, SO what is the value str_params?  Is cdate = NULL

Comment: No cdate is not null.. @karmafunk

Comment: Try it without the URLEncode. Looks like all your query params are failing.

Comment: @RakeshSharma i agree with him either initialize all variables $title='',$ctime=''....or else turn off the warning by error_reporting(0); in the start of php code.

Comment: Actually when i was trying to do without the URLEncoder than it was throwing an exception IllegalArgument exception thats y i had to put it.. @karmafunk

Comment: I don't think that is the answer. Looks at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295347/android-httpget-issue

Comment: It looks like it's the mistake on the Android side. The Try printing out the url before sending it to the php. The 'ftitle' and the others are not parsed as string  and as the result your url becomes `res=&title=&venue=&cdate=&ctime=&attend=&fattend`

Answer (score 0):

check which variables you are passing from android and which you are using at sever side in php code.
check it from php side with print_r($_REQUEST); exit; at start of page.
that will help you to debug and you can variables list you are passing from android.

if all fine and same variable you getting from it then it will be no problem for you at sever side.

Thanks :) 
Kuldip